# python3 tkinter grid stops while drawing 'table'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In the exercise reproduced below, grid sometimes does not finish drawing all the labels, especially when I specify larger row/column numbers (eg. 10 rows x 24 cols). Not that I anticipate ever needing so many, but would like to know the reason why the grid drawing simply stops dead.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class BuildTableApp():
    def __init__(self, root, rows, cols):
        self.frm = Frame(root)
        self.frm.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        self.cols = int(cols)
        self.rows = int(rows)
        for c in range(self.cols):
            for r in range(self.rows):
                lbl = Label(self.frm, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                            text="label", relief=RAISED)
                lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                self.frm.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
                self.frm.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = input("How many rows? ")
    assert isinstance(int(rows), int), "integers only, please"
    cols = input("How many columns? ")
    assert isinstance(int(cols), int), "integers only, please"
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_table = BuildTableApp(root, rows, cols) 
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works well with a 40x40 grid of 1600 labels; you have to wait a bit for the gui to display.

Comment: Just a blind guess, but `grid_[column|row]configure()` might be slow calls. You could try issuing them only once for each row/column.

Comment: Code works as expected. Cannot reproduce issue. What OS are you on and maybe what hardware?

Comment: @tevemadar: but I am issuing only once for each row/column, am I not?

Comment: @Mike - SMT: Ubuntu 18.04 on a Samsung 900X laptop with 256Gb SSD.

Comment: You are issuing them for each cell, so "number of rows" times for each column and "number of columns" times for each row.

Comment: @tevemadar : sorry, you are quite right. So, I created a loop for columnconfigure, and another one for rowconfigure: it worked, but struggled to finish even a 20x20 table. Then, I restarted the system and tried again, this time without any column/rowconfigure, and the result was the same!!

Comment: Switched to newly installed Debian 10 on my dual-boot system: both 20x20 and 40x40 tables show up instantaneously !!!